# Getting error in lightning record picker, while using the parent object field in the filter criteria

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am creating a lightning record picker on the User object,  and want to select users with certain profiles only, but getting the error as below. following is my filter criteria

```
filter = {
    criteria: [
        {
            fieldPath: 'IsActive',
            operator: 'eq',
            value: true
        },
        {
            fieldPath: 'Profile.Name',
            operator: 'in',
            value: ['Higher Management', 'Managers']
        }
    ],
    filterLogic: '1 AND 2',
};
```

ERR_RP008 - Validation error of type WrongType: argument 'where.and[2]' with value 'ObjectValue{objectFields=[ObjectField{name='and', value=ArrayValue{values=[ObjectValue{objectFields=[ObjectField{name='or', value=ArrayValue{values=[ObjectValue{objectFields=[ObjectField{name='Name', value=ObjectValue{objectFields=[ObjectField{name='like', value=StringValue{value='%greg%'}}]}}]}]}}]}, ObjectValue{objectFields=[ObjectField{name='IsActive', value=ObjectValue{objectFields=[ObjectField{name='eq', value=BooleanValue{value=true}}]}}]}, ObjectValue{objectFields=[ObjectField{name='Profile', value=ObjectValue{objectFields=[ObjectField{name='Name', value=ObjectValue{objectFields=[ObjectField{name='in', value=StringValue{value='7-) Higher Management'}}]}}]}}]}]}}]}' contains a field not in 'User_Filter': 'Profile' @ 'uiapi/query/User'

Answer (score 0):

The lightning-record-picker component uses the [graphql wire adapter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-graphql.html). graphql uses the UI API. The [UI API doesn't support the plain Profile object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_all_supported_objects.htm).

Create a formula field (e.g. ProfileName__c) referring to the Profile on the User and reference this instead.